# How to login with Account Number-Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi guys so I am trying to login using my Account Number which is stored in an arraylist, I am unable to match the user input with the Account Number.My code is below :

**Login Method-Main Class**

```
private void Login (){

    int UserInput; 
    Scanner option = new Scanner (System.in);

    Account Account = new Account();
    ArrayList<Client> customers = bank.getCustomers(); //Gets Customer Info from Bank 
    System.out.println("What is your Account Number?");
    UserInput = option.nextInt();



        if(UserInput==Account.getAccountNumber()){
             Menu();
             int choice = UserInput();
             performAction(choice);
        //system.out.println(i+1 + ")" + customers.get(i).BasicInfo());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Account Number");
          }




    }
```

**ArrayList - Bank Class**

```
  public class Bank {

    ArrayList<Client> customers = new ArrayList<Client>(); //Adds customer details in this

        void addCustomer(Client customer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        customers.add(customer);//Adds customer from Menu to ArrayList  
    }

        Client getCustomer(int account) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return customers.get(account); //Returns Customer detail from ArrayList
    }

        ArrayList <Client> getCustomers (){
            return customers;  //Returns customers
        }

}
```

Hi guys  what I am trying to do is make the userInput in the main class be able to match the AccountNumber from the 'GetMethod" I believe it is stored in an araylist in the 'Bank' class. If it does match the Account number then the other methods function within the if statement. Right now when I enter the AccountNumber it just goes to the else statement and displays "Invalid AccountNumber". I apologise if this doesnt make sense.

Comment: Account Account = new Account(); do not use the classname to ID the object.

Comment: Or just use the proper java naming standards..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, I think you are saving account number of user somewhere else.

The account number you get from the Account class is the next account number available to assign.As when you initialize the Account class, inside the Account constructor it increases the account number. That number is returned from Account.getAccountNumber().

There is no way this can be an account number of an existing user.

**Solution:** You didn't post your customer class here. But you must have a account_number variable inside you customer class.you can set a getter for account number. Inside the bank you have list customer's. you will need to iterate through each customer and match the input account number with the account number of those customers.Your loop inside bank class could look like this:

```
  for(int i=0;i<customers.size();i++){
    if(inputAccountNumber == customers.get(i).getAccountNumber())
    {
      return true;
     }
   }
```

This is not a scalable solution. You can set a hashmap for customer with account number as key and value as the instance of customer class for that customer.

Hope this solves your problem.